# what does "ch - 'a' " mean?

Tags: java, arrays

I was going through a piece of code which i was not able to understand. Thought of checking this with our community.

In the below code, i am not able to understand what the line count[ch-'a']++ does. or how can we write the same in java 7. What the explanation says is that we have a String s and an int array count. We iterate through the string s and count the no of occurrences of the characters in s and put the frequencies of count into the array. please help!!

```
String s = "test";
   int[] count = new int[26];        
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       char ch = s.charAt(i);
       count[ch-'a']++;                     
   }
```

Comment: `'a'` is ascii 97. So it's `ch - 97`, or in the case of the first character in `s` (`t`), `164-97`

Comment: This is valid java code, even for Java 1.5.

Comment: Remember, `char`acters are just numbers, so you can add, subtract... And characters have also the additional literal with a character enclosed in `'`

Comment: @abhishek pandey Please accept an answer if it helped you.  All us newbs can use the rep

Answer (score 5):

the code is trying to count the number of occurrence of each character.

and it allocates it such that

```
a occupies position 0
b occupies position 1
etc etc
```

to get position 0, you need to call 'a' - 'a'
to get position 1, you need to call 'b' - 'a'

so what is happening in "count[ch-'a']++;"  is eqivalent to

```
int position = ch -'a'; // get position
count[position] = count [position] + 1; // increment the count in that particular position
```

Answer (score 4):

You are iterating over an array of ints `count` and incrementing the integer value at index `ch-'a'`, which results in an integer value, e.g `count['a'-'a'] == count[0]` to flag that the character exists in the string.

you subtract in `ch - 'a'` because the integer value of alphabetic characters does not start at 0.

Answer (score 2):

It means to treat the two characters like **integers** and subtract one from the other.  For instance,

```
'b' - 'a' == 1
```

In the code you posted, it's counting up all the lowercase characters into an array data structure.  In other words, the count[0] will be very large if there are many lowercase 'a's in the String, count[1] will be large if many lowecase 'b's, etc.

Comment: but the ch shall be the character at i in the for loop and its each time subtracting 'a' ie. [ch - 'a']. why is it 'a'?

Comment: @abhishekpandey Does this make sense?  I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

`count[]` is here to store occurrences of each letter from `String` passed as argument (at  `count[0]` there will be stored number of occurences of '`a`', at `count[1]` number of occurences of '`b`',... at `count[25]` occurences of '`z`').

Now in the following line:

```
char ch = s.charAt(i);
```

You store currently checked character from given String. (when  `i = 0`, it's '`t`'). Keep in mind, that each `char` can be presented as `int` (it's an **ASCII** code) . To see list of all numeric values corresponding to each `char`, you can search for the ASCII table in the Internet (e. g. [here](http://www.asciitable.com), at column "Dec"). So for '`t`' it's 116.

By saying:

```
count[ch-'a']++;
```

You mean `count[116 - 97]++`, it's `count[19]++`. Subtracting by '`a`' is subtracting by 97 and it's here to help quickly find index in the array in which you store occurrences of currently checked `char ch`. Look, for '`a`' it would be `count['a' - 'a']` (`count[0]` - first index in `count` array), for '`z`' `count[122 - 97]` (`count[25]` - last index in `count` array)